# Как добавить php локаль в windows 10

Tags: php, windows, laravel, locale

Я развернул проект на windows 10, как мне добавить в среде windows локаль как в ubuntu например:

```
sudo locale-gen uk_UA.utf8
sudo update-locale
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
echo "Europe/Kyiv" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
```